# Flash Symbol Button gotoAndPlay

Tags: flash

I'm super new to this and don't really know what I'm doing. I have a symbol button that, when rolled over I want to go to a frame and play
this is what I have and it doesn't do anything.

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
btnBasic.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, txtDisplay);

function txtDisplay(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
gotoAndPlay(69);
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a scope problem. If you want to go to and play from frame 69 of your btnBasic button you can change the code in the listener to "btnBasic.gotoAndPlay(69)".

Comment: Thanks for the response. What I needed was to go to frame 69 of the main timeline. The code I had was correct but for whatever reason it just wasn't working. I restarted flash and it worked fine.